# Arduino fsr to c# visual studio

Tags: c#, arduino, communication, sensors

Hi I'm using Arduino for my force sensors and I was wondering If I could use the input of my force sensor from Arduino to display the readings on c# visual studio textboxes? Is it possible to display calculated values on Arduino to c# visual studio textboxes as well?

Comment: Yes you can. Use Serial.Print on Arduino to print your values to the serial port and on the other side (pc app) use a serial read and show the values in the text boxes. You can easily find examples for the arduino side to print the data on serial. On the serial reading have a look here: http://csharp.simpleserial.com